# Como determinar o tamanho de um JLabel?

Tags: java, swing

Estou criando um programa, e estou fazendo o menu dele.

Mas, para fazer o menu, preciso criar um botão e estou criando esse botão utilizando imagens com o `JLabel` e utilizando o `MouseListener`. Porém, preciso saber como determinar o tamanho de uma `JLabel` para facilitar.

Answer (score 2):

Veja o [método `getSize()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getSize--) e a [classe `Dimension`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Dimension.html):

```
JLabel label = ...
Dimension d = label.getSize();
System.out.println("Largura: " + d.width + " - Altura: " + d.height);
```